# In the Smallville series, was Lex "meteor rock" infected?

Tags: dc, lex-luthor, smallville

From the very first episode of *Smallville* it is made evident that the Kryptonite meteor shower had immediate as well as delayed affects on a lot of biological matter, especially people. It is somewhat implied that exposure to the rock not only serves as a catalyst for (possibly latent) metahuman abilities, creating the early "Kryptonite freak of the week" format... but it is *also* implied that exposure can create a mental imbalance, as most humans that develop some Kryptonite-based ability *also* seem to go bad, seeking to do harm more than anything else.

Now, a *lot* of that could be put down to the mistreatment they suffered prior to their specific accident, or how others related to them afterwards... but it's odd that the majority of the infected fell to villainy. In that same pilot episode, we saw Lex wandering in a field during the impact, and the result was that he lost his hair. Considering *again* the high ratio of people who "went bad" after their incidents, though, it leads me to wonder...

Is Lex perhaps "meteor infected" at some low level, and *that's* why (besides comic history) he ended up turning into a bad guy in the series?

Granted, he doesn't have any powers (unless you count his survivability; dude went through more in that series than anybody else besides Clark, and *still* came out whole!) and yes, Lex's mindset *could* be easily placed on the emotional manipulations of his father Lionel...  but it's *also* true that he **was** physically affected by the meteors (hence the baldness).

*And,* to be fair, while Lex was insatiably curious and somewhat cutthroat in business, he *was* **genuinely protective** of Clark, his family and his friends for at least the first 4 seasons. Even in a later season where he is shot and in a coma, his mind constructed a scenario where he had a positive and warm (if financially strapped) life where he married Lana and he, Clark and Chloe were close friends. And of course, there was an episode where Black Kryptonite separated his good and evil sides into two different people. Lex himself *acknowledges*  he has a constant mental struggle to maintain his decency, saying to Clark how his friendship helps him be a better person. You can see it here, from season 4:

Granted, the writing in the series was usually top notch, blending the human drama very well with the sci-fi elements. So this could have been nothing more than playing to that drama. However, read *differently* ... this could be Lex admitting he has a *literal* internal struggle based around his personality being turned by increasing darkness he has no control over (i.e. sanity slippage due to the meteor infection.) Granted a "Villainous Luthor" is canon in most *Superman* media, and from childhood Lex *was* surrounded by less than stellar influences...but it's never been full established what mental effects Kryptonite could have on normal humans.

However, we *do* have evidence of Kryptonite exposure on Lex in *another* version of *Superman* causing **some form** of sanity slippage, as seen in *Superman & Batman: Public Enemies* a few years later. Granted, Lex was *deliberately* shooting it into his system, but the basis is still the same, as seen here:

Could it be that, in the *Smallville* universe at least, Lex was actually a pretty decent person, or at least had the *capacity* to be... but his exposure to the meteor rocks slowly made him go more and more insane, thus facilitating his villainous turn in later years?

Plot convenience aside, such an infection would also explain his high survivability throughout the series, the loss of hair, and the gradual change in his mental state, despite other occasions showing him to be a reasonable person.

Comment: The only clear effect of the meteor on him was superhuman immune system and baldness.

Comment: @SteveHarrington I agree; those are the only _clear_ effects. However, we _have_ seen similar side effects on other meteor infected. This was one of the most nuanced portrayals of Lex Luthor in any Superman media, so it provides an opportunity to look at Lex as more than merely a "career criminal with no real reason." I'm wondering if _this_ version could have been _turned bad_ more than just be "born that way." Admittedly, this version _also_ seems somewhat less scientifically brilliant than most versions.